# using the AD8475 as a single ended output

Tags: adc, differential, buffer, single-ended

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fP1UNW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am putting together my schematic and I am trying to figure out if I can use the AD8475 as a single ended output buffer.  AD8475 Found here: http://www.analog.com/en/products/amplifiers/adc-drivers/fully-differential-amplifiers/ad8475.html

My setup has 4 incoming wires (3 signals with a common gnd) going into 3 separate AD8475's.  I then have 4 inputs into my ADC and I would like to have 3 signals all with a common ground again.  This is very similar to the example in the AD7176-2 datasheet but is single ended with 3 buffers rather than differential with two. 
ADC7176-2 found here: http://www.analog.com/en/products/analog-to-digital-converters/ad-converters/ad7176-2.html

In the schematic/datasheet it only talks about differential output.  Could I tie all OUT- terminals of the 3 Buffers together and then add a 10ohm resistor before the ADC and capacitors across from all the OUT+'s to the OUT- as in the fully differential mode?

My reason for using the Buffer (AD8475) is I need a VOCM so I can adjust the reference to 2.5V as well as scale down the input precisely.

Any suggestions or help would be great.

***UPDATE:***
added schematic.
Also the inputs to AD8475 will be scaled down to <5Vpp but it will be offset by the 2.5V reference voltage so it will be from 0V-5V.

looking at the AD8475 there is also some interestingly placed capacitors, and I am guessing those will have to be adjusted as well..

I also found this http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/design-note/dn473f.pdf 
which is specifically focused on using TI differential amplifiers as single ended ones.  They seem to indicate all that needs to be done is not connect the out-, which doesn't make sense to me....

Thanks,

scarlson

Comment: It seems pretty silly to use this part with single ended signals, while wanting a single ended output.

Comment: @MattYoung I agree, but is it possible?  I already use that chip so I have plenty.  Is it going to degrade the signal if I just tie the - low?